# How can I authenticate at Azure Container registry from an Logic App

Tags: azure-container-service

I'm working on an application that needs to start a container whenever a message is received on a message queue. To do so I decided to use an Azure Logic App for monitoring the queue and Azure Container Instances for running the containers.

The logic app is very simple, it consists of the following steps:

1. Monitor the queue
2. Start a container via the "Create Container Group"-connector.

This works very well for public containers. However, now I want to switch to containers in my private Container Registry and I run into an authentication issue with the Container Registry:

*"The image 'something/somethingstub:latest' in container group '' is not accessible. Please check the image and registry credential.""*

I have tried to authenticate with the registry by configuring the "imageRegistryCredentials" options as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.containerinstance/containergroups). But that did not help.

Does anyone have any pointers on how to proceed?

Comment: Believe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70986949/15802844) would be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you check the image name? for private registry the image name starts with the server host name, e.g. if it's azure registry, the image name should be something like myregistry.azurecr.io/myimage:latest

When you configure the registry credential in logic app, the "imageRegistryServer" should match the server in image name.

one of the example you can find here: https://lnx.azurewebsites.net/serverless-2-azure-logic-apps-and-azure-container-instances/