# Azure LogicApp connecting to Azure Container Registry

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I've setup the 'Identity' in LogicApp, added necessary AcrPull access in the container registry, but can't get the logic app to access the private container registry in Azure (with the error;

```
"error": {
  "code": "InaccessibleImage",
  "message": "The image 'xxx.azurecr.io/xx:xx' in container group 'ContainerGroupName' is not accessible. Please check the image and registry credential."
}
```

I've tried setting the imageRegistryCredentials as well, but not entirely sure which user to specify. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you configure the registry credential in logic app, the `imageRegistryServer` should **match the server in image name**.

Here is an example that you can refer to: [Azure Logic Apps and Azure Container Instances](https://lnx.azurewebsites.net/serverless-2-azure-logic-apps-and-azure-container-instances/).

Answer (score 0):

Found these amazing examples [1](https://soltisweb.com/blog/detail/2021-09-01-deployinganimagefromazurecontainerregistrytoazurelogicapps), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59466714/azure-logic-apps-waiting-for-an-aci-container-to-terminate-to-get-its-logs)  which shows connecting azure logic app with azure container registry. Logic app's ACI connectors are used for successfully connecting with ACR and spinning up container instances on demand.