# How create azure logic app for Azure ACR?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, acr

Is there any trigger & action for **ACR** in **Azure Logic App**?

Thanks

Comment: Believe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70986949/15802844) would be useful

Answer (score 0):

You will find a list of Logic App connectors [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/apis-list). ACR is not included but may be in future. You will need to build a [custom connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/apis-list#custom).