# azure logic apps: waiting for an ACI container to terminate to get its logs

Tags: azure, docker, azure-logic-apps, azure-container-instances

I have an Azure logic app that correctly creates an Azure Container Instance. The container starts, does its job and terminates. I need to collect its logs with the appropriate connector and write them to an azure blob.

I have all the pieces in place but I do not know how to wait for the container to terminate before using the "get logs of container" connector to collect logs.

If the container job would last a predictable amount of time, I could use the Delay connector before getting the logs and it would suffice (I've tried with short jobs and it works well). 
But my jobs may last several hours, depending on some external factors, so the Delay technique does not work.

I've tried with the "Until" connector, together with delay and the "get properties of a container group" container to wait until the state of the container is not "terminated", but without success (maybe I did it wrong). Anyway this can be quite expensive, since every "check" is billed.

How can I wait for the container to terminate before asking for its logs?

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

starting from Charles Xu's answer,  the correct sequence when setting the variable is
[image]

this uses the "state" container instance variable instead of "provisioning state". The latter is about the creation of the container group, the first is about the state of the container instance, which is what I need.
I added a delay to decrease the number of (paid) runs of the connector.

Comment: Why not accept my answer instead of copy the solution while it helps you solve the problem?!

Comment: because it is incomplete and does not work, as is. I'll be very glad to accept your answer if you edit it and make it work as intended, for instance using the right parameter (state) and the mandatory foreach. Having only one, complete answer it would surely be more useful to the community, and that is paramount. thanks.

Comment: Why does it not work? If you create only one instance and it would work well. I did not know all the info that you really want, no one will know it except you. In SO, the community only can provide an idea to solve the problem, not the entire answer.

Comment: I'm sorry @CharlesXu, but this is what I needed:  "I do not know how to wait for the container to terminate". Your useful answer tells when the container is correctly deployed, not when it terminates its execution. As a matter of fact you queried for the "provisioningState" property, not the "state" property. The first hold the provisioning state, the latter the execution state.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the logs of a container group and nobody knows when it can terminate. In the logic app, you can use a variable to store the state of the container group and then use an until control the loop which will get the terminate of the container group until it comes true.

Here are the steps:

1. Create a container group;
2. Get the provision state of the container group;
3. Initialize a variable to store the provision state of the container group;
4. In the untile, get the provision state of the container group until the state is equal to terminate;
5. Get the logs of the container group.

The whole structure:

[image]

The Initialize variable and Until steps:

[image]

Comment: this is an excellent starting point, albeit not entirely working for my aims. Please refer to my answer for details. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned using "Until" in logic app maybe expensive, here I provide another solution for your reference.

We can create a [time trigger azure function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp) and set the cron expression every 1 minutes, [create a service plan(free tier)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale) for the function, so we don't need to pay for the running cost of the function(but may pay for the storage of the function).

The function will run every 1 minute. In function we need to get the properties of the container by using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/container-instances/containergroups/get) rest api and then if the state is "terminated", call the logic app request to trigger the logic app(the logic app should be created as "[When a HTTP request is received](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-reqres#add-request-trigger)").

The function code(in local, before deployed to azure) should be as below:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace hurytimeFun
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

            //1. using rest api to get the properties of your container

            //2. if the state is "terminated"
                // call the logic app request to trigger the logic app
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it would be helpful to your problem~

Comment: this methods is cool and valid in general, but for my case it is not applicable since I have many logic apps programmatically provisioned, and your answer would require additional coordination work. thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Once a container terminates, everything is lost. You could install the log-analytics-containers from the Azure marketplace for logging and log before the container terminates

Comment: when a container terminates, nothing is lost: you can easily read its logs, for instance, if you do not delete the container group.