# Run Speech service on Azure Container Instance

Tags: speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services, azure-container-instances

I am trying to host the speech service docker image on our Azure Container Instance.  I have followed steps described in the microsoft docs (link below):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/deploy-speech-on-container-instances

So the steps i did are:

1. created speech resource via Azure portal
2. copied the key and endpoint
3. copied yaml template from the above document and substituted the following fields: containergroupname, username, password, containername, imageName, serviceEndpointUrl  and ApiKey 
   fields.

When I run the yaml file via cloudshell I get the error:

> The image
>   'containerpreview.azurecr.io/microsoft/cognitive-services-speech-to-text:latest'
>   in container group 'xxxcontainergroup' is not accessible. Please check
>   the image and registry credential.

I have rechecked the credentials and they are correct.
I am happy to paste the yaml file, but it is the same template defined in the microsoft docs with just values substituted.

Any help will be much appreciated.

**edit**: Below is my yaml file:

`apiVersion: 2018-10-01
location: uksouth
name: voicetranscriptionservicegroup
imageRegistryCredentials:
  - server: containerpreview.azurecr.io
    username: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx
    password: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx
properties:
  containers:
  - name: voicetranscriptionservice
    properties:
      image: containerpreview.azurecr.io/microsoft/cognitive-services-speech-to-text
      environmentVariables: # These env vars are required
        - name: eula
          value: accept
        - name: billing
          value: https://uksouth.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issuetoken
        - name: apikey
          value: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 4 # Always refer to recommended minimal resources
          memoryInGb: 8 # Always refer to recommended minimal resources
      ports:
        - port: 5000
  osType: Linux
  restartPolicy: OnFailure
  ipAddress:
    type: Public
    ports:
    - protocol: tcp
      port: 5000
tags: null
type: Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups`

Comment: Did you first complete and submit the [Cognitive Services Speech Containers Request form](https://aka.ms/speechcontainerspreview/) to request access to the container? It's required by Microsoft Azure for `bringing the power of Speech AI to containers`, please notice the requirement in the section [`Request access to the container registry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/deploy-speech-on-container-instances#request-access-to-the-container-registry).

Comment: Your current case is different from the other two SO threads https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50226811/how-can-i-authenticate-at-azure-container-registry-from-an-logic-app and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49498695/using-azure-container-registry-creating-new-azure-container-instance-from-c-shar which be similar with yours.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I submitted my request form and got the username and password. Also, I checked the imageregistry name and they match the public preview name for Speech service api https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/cognitive-services-container-support#public-preview-container-registry-containerpreviewazurecrio

Answer (score 0):

There is not any obvious issue in your yaml file changed from the template sample of the offical document [`Deploy the Speech Service container to Azure Container Instances`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/deploy-speech-on-container-instances#create-an-azure-container-instance-resource-from-the-azure-cli).

However, I never see that you have did the required necessary first step is to request the access permission for the container registry of Speech service in your issue description. So please make sure you have done it which be required in the offical documents as below. I think it's your real issue possibly.

Fig 1. from [`Deploy the Speech Service container to Azure Container Instances`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/deploy-speech-on-container-instances#request-access-to-the-container-registry)

[image]

Fig 2. from [`Container support in Azure Cognitive Services`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/cognitive-services-container-support#containers-in-azure-cognitive-services)

[image]

Fig 3. **IMPORTANT**: to complete and submit the **[Cognitive Services Speech Containers Request form](https://aka.ms/speechcontainerspreview/)**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Peter. I did fill the Microsoft Speech Container Service Request form and got a welcome email from speechc@microsoft.com. I followed the link from the email which generated the username and password.
The only thing I could see is that I got the email a month ago and I generated the password then. I am not sure if there is any expiry time for the username/password which we specify in the yaml to get the private container instance

Comment: @jack I don't know the details of the policy about expiry time. If you have complete the access request, just try again to check the result whether be fine without error.